# Blank python IDLE window when opening python file on macOS

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

For some reason, whenever I try to open a python script that has around ~450 lines of code, IDLE's windows simply appears empty and when I try to run it doesn't run anything either... However, if I try to run a smaller program it works for some reason. Does anybody know how I am able to run a python script on my Mac besides IDLE or how to fix the IDLE window being blank whenever I open a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn how to run Python Python programs on a Mac, read Chapters 1 and 4 of [Python Setup and Usage](https://docs.python.org/3/using/index.html).  Running from an IDLE editor is just one way.

IDLE uses the tkinter module which wraps the tcl/tk GUI framework.  Did you read and follow the instructions of how to replace the [buggy tcl/tk](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) that Apple supplies?  Read the entire page before starting!  Ignoring this page is the most common reason people have problems with IDLE on the Mac.  There are a few others, but I do not remember one that matches your description.